Cross-referencing source blocks using LaTeX attributes for export
The goal is to reference one source block (A) within another (C) that has LaTeX attributes, and export the latter. As attempted, the attributes are ignored. B is provided as a comparison, and works as expected. D is a variant of C that exports as desired if the results header is manually removed, which is far from satisfactory.
Any lead would be appreciated.
#+title: debug
#+select_tags: export

# ~Ctrl-x org-export-dispatch~

* A                                                                :noexport:

#+name: org-list
#+begin_src org
  - foo
  - bar
  - qux
#+end_src

* B

# exports as itemize* environment

#+attr_LaTeX: :environment itemize*
  - foo
  - bar
  - qux

* C

# exports as verbatim environment

#+attr_LaTeX: :environment itemize*
#+header: :noweb yes
#+begin_src org
<<org-list>>
#+end_src

* D

#+header: :export none
#+header: :noweb yes
#+header: :results raw
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (concat "#+attr_LaTeX: :environment itemize*\n"
          (org-babel-ref-resolve "org-list"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+attr_LaTeX: :environment itemize*
- foo
- bar
- qux

*Org LATEX Export*
% Created 2024-10-13 Sun 02:00
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{user}
\date{\today}
\title{debug-28}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={user},
 pdftitle={debug-28},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 30.0.50 (Org mode 9.6.11)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\section{B}
\label{sec:org309acfc}

\begin{itemize*}
\item foo
\item bar
\item qux
\end{itemize*}

\section{C}
\label{sec:orgb2bbe1f}

\section{D}
\label{sec:org594b1bd}

\begin{itemize*}
\item foo
\item bar
\item qux
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}

Side notes:

The documentation on export settings
From the setup I expected only nodes marked  export to be exported. It turns out they are exported by default, hence the :noexport: tag for A.
Is there a way to recast the :noexport: tag as a property?


What does the .tex file look like? Please add it to your question.
